# Finding TOC Layers Type (layer,grouplayer,..) and layerindex of a layer

Tags: arcobjects

How can i find the type of the layers in TOC ?
these types are very important to me :

1.layer (that has a valid datasource)

2.layer (that lose its datasource because of changing the address of its datasource )

3.GroupLayer

And i want to know about the index of the layer that we have with ILayer. A function like this :
Public Function GetLayerIndex(mLayer as ILayer) as long

Answer (score 6):

You examine the interfaces which a particular layer implements. All layers implement [ILayer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000006z1000000). If you open up the documentation link for the interface, you will see which classes implement this general interface.

Common layer types (in context of your question) are [FeatureLayer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/FeatureLayerClass_Class/0012000000sv000000/) (implements [IFeatureLayer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/0012/0012000004tp000000.htm) among others), [GroupLayer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/0012/0012000000vz000000.htm) ([ICompositeLayer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/0012/0012000002wn000000.htm), [IGroupLayer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/0012/0012000005z1000000.htm)) etc. You get the idea - when exploring the plethora of interfaces layers can implement, it's good to refer to the list of classes implementing ILayer as a great starting point.

As for the second part, layers which are not connected due to an inaccessible data source will typically be marked as invalid (red exclamation mark). The [ILayer.Valid](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000770000000) indicates whether this is or is not the case.

Finally, the third part of your question. Layer indices are assigned either at the top level (the index which goes as a parameter to [IMap.Layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Layer_Property/001200000m9r000000/)) or within a particular layer container, e. g. a composite (group) layer. The only way to get retrieve the index for an existing layer is to loop through the map or a composite layer and compare the items. This will work only at a single level and will not work reliably when layers are nested with group layers. That being said, layer indices are generally not a good idea to refer to layers.

Comment: +1 Good answer.  While I agree that using indices is not _best practice_, it is nevertheless _common practice_ - Esri's REST api uses indices to access layers within a [mapservice](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/mapserver.html).

Comment: Absolutely right, but aren't indices in map services different? As far as I know, in ArcGIS Server map services they are unique for the whole service. And even in this case I do not believe it's ideal - every time you add a layer somewhere in the middle, your layer indices shift. Luckily at AGS 10, at least for WMS services, there is a new option to use the layer name from MXD/MSD as the WMS layer name, instead of the index.

Comment: Yeah, whenever a new layer is added to a mapservice all the client web apps need to be re-config'd.  It is possible to make an extra query at initialization time to build a dictionary associating name with index (id), but that is a pain.  Sure would simplify things if Esri just provided some Layer property whose uniqueness (UniqueName) is enforced along with a method to find layer by that property.